# Network Bridge inside VM for LXD

Tags: networking, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, lxc, lxd

I use ubuntu 16.04 in a kvm virtual machine. For lxd containers I try to make a network bridge, so the containers are available in our local network.

The interface file looks like this:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
   bridge-ifaces eth0
   bridge-ports eth0
   up ifconfig eth0 up
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   gateway 192.168.0.1
   bridge_stp off
   bridge_waitport 0
   bridge_fd 0
```

In the `lxd init` config I select the br0 interface. My lxd default profile has also the bridge selected.

When I setup now a new container, I don't get an IP for it.

`brctl show` gives this:

```
bridge name    bridge id            STP enabled      interfaces
br0            8000.5254008fde71    no               eth0
                                                     vethCH64WJ
```

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to route the traffic, without using the network bridge:

```
ip route add 10.0.6.0/24 via 192.168.0.16 dev eth1
```

A solution with network bridge is still welcome!

Another way is, to use a bridge interface on host (br0), not the kvm bridge. The containers get there IPs from the host.

Answer (score 0):

This could be an emulation issue. You could try running:

`dhclient eth0 -v`

in the container and then checking out [a related question for arm/qemu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/817196/how-do-i-get-ipv4-inet-working-in-a-arm-lxc-container-running-on-intel-host) if you get an error message à la *Error getting interfaces*.

Comment: Thank you! When I remember correctly the problem was, that the firewall on the kvm host got confuse, because the route back from a package goes different then it comes. This was happen because I used not the bridge from bridge-utils on the host. I had the kvm bridge. Changes to a real bridge on the host has fix that issue.